# Get data from mysql db using a variable

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables, protected

I'm trying to get data from a mysql database using an object which is, in fact, a variable:

```
try {
$mysqlcon = new PDO($dbserver, $db['user'], $db['pass'], $dboptions);
// Selecting database "user" to get data about a specific client
if(($user_data = $mysqlcon->query("SELECT * FROM $dbname.user;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) === false)
{
    echo '$#!+ happens, Critical DataBase Error!';// error on db select
}

echo 'Country: '.$user_data[$clientuid]['nation']; // This is not working, it gives nothing
echo 'Country: '.$user_data['OISnyJzyjA63XkPB6xla8hjms3M=']['nation']; // BUT This works perfectly               
// DEBUGGING
echo $clientuid; // it outputs: OISnyJzyjA63XkPB6xla8hjms3M=
var_dump($clientuid); // and this is the important thing, it outputs this: object(TeamSpeak3_Helper_String)#27 (2) { ["string":protected]=> string(28) "OISnyJzyjA63XkPB6xla8hjms3M=" ["position":protected]=> int(0) }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Database Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
```

`echo $clientuid;` outputs: `OISnyJzyjA63XkPB6xla8hjms3M=`

This is not working, it gives nothing:

```
echo 'Country: '.$user_data[$clientuid]['nation'];
```

This works perfectly:

```
echo 'Country: '.$user_data['OISnyJzyjA63XkPB6xla8hjms3M=']['nation'];
```

`var_dump($clientuid);` yields this:

```
object(TeamSpeak3_Helper_String)#27 (2) {
    ["string":protected]=> string(28) "OISnyJzyjA63XkPB6xla8hjms3M=" 
    ["position":protected]=> int(0)
}
```

Comment: Well hey, good luck. Do you have a question?

Comment: `$user_data[$clientuid]['nation']; // This is not working, it gives nothing` - It should give you a warning.

Answer (score 1):

`$user_data` is an object and has a `protected` string property and obviously a magic `__tostring()` method that returns the string property when the object is accessed as a string (like `echo`). Without the `__tostring()` method you would get:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class TeamSpeak3_Helper_String could not be converted to string

If the string property was `public` then you could just access it:

```
echo 'Country: '.$user_data[$clientuid->string]['nation'];
```

But it is `protected` and not accessible and you would get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property TeamSpeak3_Helper_String::$string

When used as an array index it is not forcing a string, so to force it to fire the `__tostring()` magic method, cast to `(string)` will work (though there are probably several ways to do it):

```
echo 'Country: '.$user_data[(string)$clientuid]['nation'];
```

Or use quotes:

```
echo 'Country: '.$user_data["$clientuid"]['nation'];
```

Answer (score -1):

$clientuid is an object not a simply string value, fetch value fro $clientuid first into a variable and then use that variable.

i dont have worked with TeamSpeak3_Helper_String object but after some searching i found some that probably you should use `__toString()` method to convert it into string first.

refer to following links, these maybe helpful

https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/TeamSpeak3_Helper_String/-/php-teamspeak3_helper_string-class-examples.html

https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/class_team_speak3___helper___string.html#a5558c5d549f41597377fa1ea8a1cefa3